# Google Chrome high I/O writes

Tags: chrome, io

I left the laptop on with Google Chrome opened and [iotop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) running overnight (~9 hours). This is what it showed for the chrome process:

```
 PID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ DISK WRITE>  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
1879 be/4 riccardo      6.34 M      3.03 G  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers
```

It's detecting an **enormous** amount of writes coming from the chrome command. Not sure how to deal with that since there is no apparent reason for those writes (I only had local PDFs in the ~10 tabs open), I didn't download anything. Unfortunately I don't know where it wrote those 3GB.

I'm aware that Chrome [reads a lot on windows](https://www.engadget.com/2018/04/07/chrome-cleanup-download-scan/) but those 3GB it wrote? It sounds like too much verbose logs, I can't think about anything else.

Also, as I'm writing this question, it already did another 30MB of disk writes.

Comment: Having the same issue, maybe related to this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=52663